# How to express "to slide out of your hand"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

In the dictionary

> **[slip](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slip_1?q=slip)** [intransitive] (+ adv./prep.) to slide out of position or out of your hand
>
> *His hat had slipped over one eye.*
>
> *The fish slipped out of my hand.*
>
> *The child slipped from his grasp and ran off.*
>
> *(figurative) She was careful not to let her control slip.*

---

Look at this picture

[image]

Should we say "**He may slip out of / from the cliff**" or "**His hands may slip out of / from the cliff**"?

Another picture

[image]

Should we say "**the children may slip out of their dad's hands**"?

Or this one which we often see in films, a man may be hanging from his friend who is trying to grip the man's hands to prevent him from fall deep onto the ground.

[image]

**What should we say in this situation?**

Comment: For the last example, you say *his friend who is trying to grip the man's hands*. But actually it could be *the man who is trying to grip his friend's hands*. Or they could *both* be gripping each other's hands / wrists. Hopefully the *father* in the preceding example isn't just expecting his children to hang on tight (they probably don't have strong enough hands to do this, so as a responsible parent, *he* should be gripping *their* hands / wrists). But in both cases I'd probably say ***the man may lose his grip***, even if whoever he's gripping might also be trying to maintain the link..

Comment: In the case of the man climbing the rock face, 'He may slip' is probably sufficient. He isn't _in_ the cliff, so he can't slip _out of_ it.